# latest version of JDBC driver from MS is using (deprecated) ADAL libraries. What are the plans for MSAL?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

We've received a recommendation to switch from ADAL libraries for authentication, to MSAL libraries.
So we're going to do that.

On closer inspection, a scenario is that we use SQL server JDBC driver from Microsoft to connect to DB using AAD authentication. This JDBC driver internally uses ADAL. The latest version of JDBC driver from Microsoft is still using ADAL. When is MS planning to migrate their JDBC driver to use MSAL instead of ADAL?

See also:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration
"Starting June 30th, 2020, we will no longer add new features to ADAL. We'll continue adding critical security fixes to ADAL until June 30th, 2022."

Comment: This sounds like a question that you should post to the issue tracker on https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc instead of posting at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the tip!